# SQL Server query to generate dynamic columns

Tags: sql-server, pivot

I have two tables - one is state and other one is for Job titles.

I want to write a query which will output me something like this:-

```
Job titles  State name1  State name2
Job title1      200         300
Job title2      500         600
```

How can I write this query in SQL Server.

Answer (score 3):

I have no idea what your schema looks like, but it sounds like you want to change it to have three tables: JobTitle, State, and JobTitle_State_Salary.  That way you're not repeating either job titles or states in order to tie to salary.

However, addressing the problem as written (and making the assumption that salary travels with state), something like this should do the trick:

```
WITH [CTE] AS
(
    SELECT [Title], [State], [Salary]
    FROM [JobTitle]
         INNER JOIN [StateSalary]
             ON [JobTitle].[ID] = [StateSalary].[JobTitleID]
)
SELECT
    [Title], [State name1], [State name2]
FROM
    [CTE]
    PIVOT
    (
        MAX([Salary])
            FOR [State] IN ([State name1], [State name2])
    ) AS [P]
```

SQLFiddle example [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/520d0/1).

Answer (score 1):

As zimdanen said, it would be difficult to write the query without knowing the exact table structure.

I assumed for structure that *JobTitle* table has *JobTitleId* and *JobTitle* fields, and that *state_salary* table has *JobTitleId*, *State*, and *Salary* as fields.

**USING PIVOT TABLE**

```
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT A.JOB_TITLE,B.STATE,B.SALARY FROM dbo.JOB_TITLE A INNER JOIN dbo.STATE_SALARY B 
ON A.JOB_TITLE_ID = B.JOB_TITLE_ID)AS SOURCE_TABLE PIVOT 
(SUM(SALARY) FOR STATE IN (STATE1,STATE2)) AS PivotTable
```

**Without Pivot Table**

```
SELECT A.JOB_TITLE,SUM(CASE WHEN B.STATE = 'State1' THEN B.SALARY ELSE 0 END) STATE1,      SUM(CASE WHEN B.STATE = 'State2' THEN B.SALARY ELSE 0 END) STATE2
FROM dbo.JOB_TITLE A INNER JOIN dbo.STATE_SALARY B 
ON A.JOB_TITLE_ID = B.JOB_TITLE_ID
GROUP BY A.JOB_TITLE
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using sqlserver 2005 or greater you can try using pivot table